# Construct a conformal mapping from $\Bbb C$ Onto $R$ if such a map exists. And explain why if does not exist.

Tags: complex-analysis, analysis, self-learning, conformal-geometry

Let $R$ be the domain obtained by removing the non negative real numbers from $\Bbb C$.

Construct a conformal mapping from $\Bbb C$ Onto $R$ if such a map exists. And explain why if does not exist.

---

I think that $f$ is assumed as such a map from $\Bbb C \to R$

---

As a given hint at the back page of the book, conformal isomorphism and riemann mapping theorem should be used.

---

But I dont understand why I need to use conformal isomorphism. And what is conformal isomorphism? Please explain when, why, how I need to use xonformal isomorphism? And how to prove this question? Thank you.

Comment: Can you map $R$ to the upper half plane?

Comment: Yes! $f(z)=e^{i\theta}\frac{z-\alpha}{z-\alpha}$ for $Im\alpha\gt0$ @lhf

Comment: Hopefully it is true!@lhf

Answer (score 8, accepted):

$R$ is simply-connected, so by the Riemann mapping theorem there exists a conformal map $f:R \to \mathbb{D}$. Suppose there is a conformal map $g:\mathbb{C} \to R$, then $f \circ g$ is a conformal map $\mathbb{C} \to \mathbb{D}$. Since $\mathbb{D}$ is bounded, $f \circ g$ is constant (Liouville's theorem). As $g$ itself is not constant, this implies $f$ is not injective (in fact, this implies $f$ is constant). But $f$ is univalent as a conformal map. So we obtain a contraction.

Comment: The reason why f is not one to one, which is fault is f is conformal. And in order to be a conformal map, f must be 1-1 analytic function. Right?

Comment: Thank you so much. Got it well!

Comment: What did you define the set $\Bbb D$?

Comment: $\Bbb D$ is proper subset of $R$. Isnt it?

Comment: We can even see explcitly that  $z\mapsto \frac1{1+\sqrt z}$ maps $R$ conformally *into* the unit disk (which is enough): $\sqrt z$ takes to the right half plane, adding one takes us $1$ away from the origin, then reciprocals bring us into $\mathbb D$. And the biholomorphic map $R\to\mathbb D$ is not hard to find either

Comment: $\Bbb D$ is the open unit disk and $f$ must be 1-1 as a conformal map